# connection asp.net project to azure database fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Trying to connect ASP.Net code first project to Azure. At this stage it launching application online as project was published. I can browse pages, but when I try to create new dynamic pages it gives me an error. My project works fine locally. 
I uploaded project using Azure SDK and used info from azure such as the server name and connection string. Here it is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PhClub" connectionString="Server=tcp:phclub.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=PhClub;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myloginname for azure;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-PhClub-20170304023453.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-PhClub-20170304023453;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

However, there was one thing which cached my eye but i don't know what it means and how to fix it. In App_data folder i have two databases, but in the publish window I see three of them: 
[image: Publish window]
As you can see something is wrong with last one. 
Here how it looks in preview window:
[image: Preview window]
Looking for your advise since this is my first solo project. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What specifically is the error?

Comment: Error.
An error occurred while processing your request. this is all i got on page

Comment: You need to figure out the underlying error. Enable your application to display error details in the browser, or add proper logging to your application.

Comment: what do u mean by proper login?

Comment: Logging, not login. Logging means that when certain events (such as unhandled exceptions) happen in your application, that you make a record of it so that you can see what happened. Look into [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), [SEQ](https://getseq.net/), [Elmah](https://elmah.github.io/) etc.

Comment: i see. ok Thanks. However but what i see, database is not working at all. Not storing any info.

Comment: That's why you need to add logging: it will tell you exactly what the error is that's keeping it from working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" at the end of the PhClub connection string.

Comment: trying your advise. Getting conflicts now.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: my login name to azure is like a email, lets say gmail. It give me error that it cannot open server gmail requested by the login....

Comment: Azure will restrict your apps by IP. You need to allow your local IP to the firewall via Azure, check this video out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDBQYssOOAw

Comment: watched.i  created a rule for current usr. however in object browser i dont see that connection to azure, only local. that is the whole problem - i cant connect to azure db

Comment: See if you can manually add it. What happens when you run publish web now? SQL Management studio is a good tool for testing DB connections.

Comment: the same error, Web deployment task failed. source=tcp:phclub.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=PhClub;persist security info=False;user id=*****@***;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False".
Cannot open server "gmail.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ignore the @ symbol with \ before or double it like @@.
Because with  azure @ separates loginName@server.

An alternative is to create a new user/login in the database, which's username doesn't contain a @ and use this user in the connection string.

Comment: you mean something like \name@gmail.com\ ?

Comment: No like name\@gmail.com or name@@gmail.com. I don't know whether it works but I answer from my mobile phone and can't prove.

Comment: @maxb I edited the answer, because I don't know whether it works with the @ in the user id in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If we create `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in our web.config file, then we could see the details error message. We could get more info about [how to troubleshoot a web app in Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio)

We could debug it with following 2 ways:

1.Make sure that the connectionstring for dbcontext is the azure sql connectionstring

2.Make sure that Azure sql could be accessed by azure service.(Allowed default). More detail info about azure sql firewall please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers. It seems that problem was in connection string login credentials, i deleted web app, server and database, recreated it again with new simple login name. Changed all of the login name and password in connection strings. This way i got rid of the error.